# How can i assign a string values to a List<string>

Tags: c#, generics

I have code as follows

```
string str=sbr.ToString();
```

Here i will get all the table names from SQLLITE in str

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> key in tableNames)
// Here i am geting only one n tablenames so i would like to assign str values to tableNames so that it will search for all if my != condition fails

{
    if (str.Contains(key.Key))
    {
        if (key.Key != "DBVERSION")
        {
            bool verify = false;
            if(DBUpdate(tableNames, key.Key)==false)
            {
                GetEndDate(tableNames, key.Key);
            }
            DBInsert(tableNames, key.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to assign the `str` value to `tablename` field and I would like to compare with the `key` value can anyone help me?

```
        public bool Update(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> tableNames, SQLiteConnection m_oConn)
    {
        bool m_bFlag = false;           
        SQLiteDataAdapter adp=new SQLiteDataAdapter("select tbl_name from sqlite_master where type='table' order by tbl_name",m_oConn);

        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        if (m_oConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            m_oConn.Open();
        }
        StringBuilder sbr=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder collumnNames = new StringBuilder();

        adp.Fill(ds);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
                sbr.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()+",");
        }
        string str=sbr.ToString();


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> key in tableNames)
            {

                if (str.Contains(key.Key))
                {
                    if (key.Key != "DBVERSION")
                    {
                        bool verify = false;
                        if(DBUpdate(tableNames, key.Key)==false)
                        {
                            GetEndDate(tableNames, key.Key);
                        }
                        DBInsert(tableNames, key.Key);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> ColNameKey in key.Value)
                    {
                        string strd = "";

                        List<string> values = ColNameKey.Value;
                        if(values[0].Contains("-"))
                        {
                            strd="DATE";
                        }
                        else if (values[0].Contains("'"))
                        {
                            strd = "CHAR";
                        }
                        else if (values[0].Contains("."))
                        {
                            strd = "FLOAT";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strd = "INT";
                        }

                        //GetDataTypes(ColNameKey.Key,out strd);
                        collumnNames.Append(ColNameKey.Key + " "+strd+",");

                    }
                    m_oCmd.CommandText = "create table " + key.Key + "(" + collumnNames.ToString().TrimEnd(',') + ")";
                    m_oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sw.WriteLine(key.Key+" table created");
                    DBInsert(tableNames, key.Key);
                }


            }
            //m_oConn.Close();
         m_bFlag = true;
         return m_bFlag;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if I got what you mean (which I'm totally unsure) then you need smth like this:

```
tablenames = new List<string>() { str };
```

or this (for C# 2.0)

```
tablenames = new List<string>(new string[] { str });
```

Comment: i am getting the error as follows Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>>' C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\dB UPDATE TOOL\DBUpdateTool\DAO\Trans.cs 70 26 DBDAO

Comment: @user, ok, it's totally unclear what do you want to achieve. I got that I misunderstood you, but what do you want I didn't got. Can you rephrase a question?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shot in the dark at what you are trying to achieve, I think your `tableNames` is actually a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`, and you want to add `str` to it somehow.

For that you obviously need *two* keys. I’ll call the other one `key2`. You can add a string to the list by saying:

```
tableNames[key][key2].Add(str);
```

However, this assumes that the keys are already present in the dictionary and the list is already instantiated. If you cannot be sure of that, you need to check for it:

```
if (!tableNames.ContainsKey(key))
    tableNames[key] = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
if (!tableNames[key].ContainsKey(key2))
    tableNames[key][key2] = new List<string>();
tableNames[key][key2].Add(str);
```

Comment: Can you post this in more clear way actually i am new to Generics concepts

Comment: @user614172: What part is unclear?

Comment: i did not get how to declare key,key2 tableNames[key][key2].Add(str);

Comment: @user614172: I cannot solve your problem for you without knowing the problem. I’m afraid that programming requires thinking; if you are unwilling to think about your problem by yourself, then nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Actually i would like to assign my string value to tablenames before it is entering in to foreach loop.. See my updated code once

Comment: @user614172: Your question makes no sense. It is not possible to *assign* a string value to a dictionary. Maybe you mean something else, but I don’t know what. Posting more code doesn’t help. You’ll need to explain *what the actual problem is*. In order to do this, you’ll have to *sit down and think about what the actual problem is*. Until you do this, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Very cryptic question... but I’ll answer it literally :)

> I would like to assign the `str` value to `tablename` field

You can do this with the following command:

```
tablename = str;
```

However, for this `tablename` would need to be of type `string`. If `tablename` is a `List<string>`, it is ambiguous what you mean; if you mean you want to make `tablename` contain *only* `str`, then it’s

```
tablename = new List<string> { str };
```

If you mean you want to *add* `str` to the list, it’s

```
tablename.Add(str);
```

However, in the latter case you need to make sure that you first instantiate the list. You can do that in the original declaration of the field, for example:

```
List<string> tablename = new List<string>();
```

I would recommend that if `tablename` is indeed a list, you should consider calling it **`tablenames`** instead to be clear.

> and I would like to compare with the `key` value can anyone help me?

There are several ways to compare strings. To compare against another string `x`, the most common ones are:

```
key.CompareTo(x)          // ← only works if key is not null
string.Compare(key, x)
```

These return `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on whether `key` is lexicographically smaller, the same, or bigger.

To compare *for equality*:

```
key.Equals(x)             // ← only works if key is not null
string.Equals(key, x)
key == x
```

These return a `bool`, i.e. either `true` or `false`.

Comment: It's hard to get what does he need here since tablenames is dictionary of dictionaries of lists (O_o), see his comment to my answer

Comment: but i am having my table name declared as follows Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>> tableNames so how can i do it for string str now

Comment: @user614172: Next time, mention this kind of important detail in your question please.